# How to generate OAUTH link for Microsoft Bot framework without using dialogs?

Tags: python, oauth, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying to create a sign-in card so that the person interacting with the card is redirected to a sign-in page and the token is then used for other purposes (like fetching information etc).

```
class SignInGeneratorService:
def __init__(self, APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD):
    SETTINGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD)
    self.ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(SETTINGS)
    activity = Activity()
    self.turn_context = TurnContext(self.ADAPTER, activity)

async def generate_raw_link(self):
    return await self.ADAPTER.get_oauth_sign_in_link(self.turn_context, "ADAuth")
```

This is what I initially tried to get the sign in link, but it doesn't seem to work (probably because we are using a dummy turn context object). Any ideas on how to do the same without having to use dialogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing what worked for me. I had to pass MicrosoftAppCredentials and set the bot identity using the bearer token I had created earlier using the Microsoft login API (needs the client id and secret for generating this). After this I was able to create a sign-in URL which could be passed on for further use.

```
    identity = await self.ADAPTER._authenticate_request(self.activity,
                                                        "Bearer *bearerToken*")
    self.app_credentials = MicrosoftAppCredentials(APP_ID, APP_PASSWORD)
    self.turn_context.turn_state[BotAdapter.BOT_IDENTITY_KEY] = identity
    sign_in_resource = await self.ADAPTER.get_oauth_sign_in_link(self.turn_context, "ADAuth", None, self.app_credentials)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, I think you can achieve this using the "signin" card. The [06.using-cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/06.using-cards) sample demonstrates how to set up the card. And, visiting the BotFramework-WebChat repo, you can test this using the [01.getting-started/a.full-bundle](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/01.getting-started/a.full-bundle/) demo. Just type in the word "signin" and the card will be presented. Clicking the button brings you to a page to log into Microsoft's live.com site.

You would only need to update the URL so it points to the service of your choice or design allowing you to acquire whatever information necessary.

Hope of help!

Comment: The example that you provided is something I have already gone through and uses to dialog prompts to send the sign-in and generate the sign-in URL internally (which is fine) but the service I'm writing is not responsible for sending the messages directly to the bot. That's why I mentioned in my question how do I generate the URL without using dialogs in the first place.